# My university's cluster doesn't connect to the internet, so I can't use conda to create an environment with python 2.7. What else can I do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, conda

A code I wish to use requires python 2.7. I thought I'll make an environment just for this code but my uni's cluster [SUSE Linux] doesn't connect to the internet for security reasons. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Anaconda on your PC in a known location (not the suggested ProgramData which is hidden and possibly protected)
2. Copy the Anaconda installation on to a memory stick
3. Create a directory where you are going to do your work on your cluster - say H:\Work
4. Copy the whole Anaconda installation to H:\Work
5. Create a shortcut to C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe in H:Work
6. Change the properties to

   cmd /k H:\Work\Anaconda2\scripts\activate.bat H:\Work\Anaconda2

   I'm just guessing that it is Anaconda2 for 2.7.  I use 3.7 which is Anaconda3.
7. Copy the shortcut to your desktop or taskbar or favourites
8. Use the shortcut to start anaconda.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the cluster has SUSE Linux.

Comment: Can you download the Linux anaconda distro to your local machine?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand, do you mean to say whether I can get the same copy of anaconda on my local machine? Yes, in that case.